# Does "up to" include what is following?

Tags: meaning

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’), all of the characters **up to** the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.

From my experience or intuition (I am not sure which), "up to" means the following is included. But I am not sure if that is correct when reading the quote. So generally speaking does "up to" mean the following is included or not?

Answer (score 2):

**Up to** does not include the slash. In your specific bash example:

> ~ gives you: $HOME
>   ~/hello gives you: $HOME/hello

Only the "~" is substituted by "$HOME", the rest of the string is then parsed. The "/" is usually used as a delimiter and so is not included as part of any substitution string unless specifically ***escaped***.

Usually **up to and including the slash** would mean "~/", and so **up to** means **up to, but not including**.  If you walk **up to** a wall, you do not end up ***in*** the wall, you are just next to it...